# Subreport not loaded when using using LoadReportDefinition

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, report-viewer2016

When I load the Report Definition on the `LocalReport` via the `LoadReportDefinition`-Method, subreports which are embedded within the report will not be loaded anymore.
I get an `rsErrorExecutingSubreport` saying that the Report Definition of the Report XY could not be loaded. In english, the error text will probably be:

```
The report definition for report 'XY' has not been specified
```

When I load the main report over the `ReportEmbeddedResource`-property, the subreport works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading the RDLC via `LoadReportDefinition`, the subreport's report definition must be loaded via the `LoadSubreportDefinition`-method.

It will take the name of the subreport as a string and the Stream which holds the sub-report as Parameters.